# What happened to CAPNG_SELECT_AMBIENT?

Tags: linux, capabilities

Three years ago, I wrote a program to manipulate the CAP_NET_RAW capability of my programs. I used the AMBIENT capability set.
But now, I'm not able to compile my program on my actual Debian distro (kernel 5.10) because CAPNG_SELECT_AMBIENT does not exist anymore in cap-ng.h.
I notice that a new constant appeared: CAPNG_SELECT_BOTH
Can someone explain what happened to CAPNG_SELECT_AMBIENT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Support for ambient capabilities was added to `libcap-ng` in [upstream version 0.8](https://github.com/stevegrubb/libcap-ng/releases/tag/v0.8), released in 2020-09-08. If you used it three years ago, you must have been using some pretty bleeding-edge distribution.

Debian 11's current version of that library (packages `libcap-ng0`, `libcap-ng-dev`) is still [0.7.9-2.2+b1](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libcap-ng&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) as of this writing.

So CAPNG_SELECT_AMBIENT has simply not arrived to the stable version of Debian yet. Debian 12 ("bookworm", the release currently in testing) seems to be getting [version 0.8.3](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bookworm&searchon=names&keywords=libcap-ng).

Comment: You asked for CAPNG_SELECT_AMBIENT: it's defined in `/usr/include/cap-ng.h`, which comes in Bookworm package `libcap-ng-dev_0.8.3-1+b3`. `libcap-ng` is not part of the "core" Linux capabilities, but an optional add-on library to make the use of the POSIX 1003.1e capabilities easier in user-space.

Comment: Well spotted, noting that it appears that libcap-ng-dev has to be installed in addition to the normal libcap-dev. I've deleted my slightly older comment since I'd been using a brute-force search over the capability.h files and realised it was incomplete (and didn't manage to fix it within the 5 min editing window).